# C# console application returns: "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a simple class with a just two methods:

```
public class SomeType
    {
        public string DoWork()
        {
            Working();
        }

        public string Working()
        {
            return "some string";
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to Build I am getting an error: 'SomeType.DoWork()': not all code paths return a value'.

I understand method DoWork should return string type, but I'm calling the method Working which returns string, so why it happeining?

Comment: This is really too broad for Stack Overflow as we cannot teach you the basics of programming. Please do take the time to follow [the official getting started guide for c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/). There are also very good books that you can find in the tag's documentation here in Stack Overflow

Comment: Do you think that `DoWork` is ever returning anything at all? (Hint: no, it's not) Do you know *why* you need it to?

Comment: I am interested to learn how people come to believe false things about programming so that I can help teach them better. Your reasoning seems to be "I am required to return; I called a function which returns; therefore I returned".  Is that a fair summary of your mental process here?

Comment: Absent a duplicate, I disagree that this question should be closed.  It is neither broad nor off-topic.  OP asked a very well-focused question.  OP provided an MVCE.  OP explained what actually happened and what he expected to happen.  While this is very much a beginner question, it's still a properly formulated question.  I admit that OP didn't "prove" that he did research, but this sort of problem is hard to research if you don't already know the answer.

Comment: This question is being discussed [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374865/1709587).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return` a string value from `DoWork` function.

this code only execute `Working` function, but didn't return string value from `DoWork` function.

```
public string DoWork()
{
    Working();
}
```

so you might return a value from `DoWork` function because `DoWork` method signature must return a string value.

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return Working();
    }

    public string Working()
    {
        return "some string";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Method `Working()` returns string to method `DoWork()`. But `DoWork()` doesn't return anything. Probably you want to use `return Working();`

You can capture the return value, modify/process/do something with it, and then you need to return something else.

Other way, you can change signature to `public void DoWork()` if you don't want to return anything from it.

But those are very basics of programming.